# Microsoft Office 2010 on PlayonLinux has incorrect icon when executing

Tags: wine, launcher, icons, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have installed MS Office 2010 over 2010 POL (v4.2.10 with Wine 2.22). The icons locked to the Unity Launcher are the correct MS Excel and Word icons, and both Excel and Word works fine when I click those icons.

However, both Excel and Word open in the Unity Launcher as the "Wine Windows Program Loader" (ie Wine Glass) icon and is grouped under it and not under Excel and Word icons.
[image: Office under the Wine Glass icon]

Here's the Excel .desktop file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Microsoft Excel 2010
Comment=PlayOnLinux
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/share/playonlinux/playonlinux --run "Microsoft Excel 2010" %F
Icon=/home/jd/.PlayOnLinux//icones/full_size/Microsoft Excel 2010
Name[fr_FR]=Microsoft Excel 2010
StartupWMClass=EXCEL.EXE
Categories=Office;Spreadsheet;
```

How can I change this behaviour to enable the Excel instances to be grouped under the Excel icon and the Word instances under the Word icon?

Comment: If you run `xprop WM_CLASS` in Terminal the mouse pointer will change into a crosshair. What's the output in Terminal if you place the crosshair over an Exel window and click?

Comment: @pomsky - I get 
`WM_CLASS(STRING) = "excel.exe", "Wine"`

Comment: Also I think you will have to escape the spaces in the name of the icon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `xprop WM_CLASS` in Terminal the mouse pointer will change into a crosshair. Place the crosshair over an open Exel window and click.

You'll probably get an output like

```
WM_CLASS(STRING) = "excel.exe", "Wine"
```

Open the `.desktop` file associated with Excel and add (or modify) a

```
StartupWMClass=excel.exe
```

line using the `WM_CLASS(STRING)` value for Excel (*case sensitive*) to the `.desktop` file.

Comment: Wow ! works perfectly.